# Does Aurora Serverless V2 have a Data API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

I've seen that V2 is out now but there is no option to have the data api and the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.regions) say it is only available on V1.

> The Data API can be enabled for Aurora Serverless v1 DB clusters using specific Aurora MySQL and Aurora PostgreSQL versions only. For more information, see Data API for Aurora Serverless v1.

Does anyone know if V2 actually does not have any such API or there's another feature that replaces it?

Answer (score 34):

Edit 2023-12-21:
It would seem our wait is coming to an end!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.enabling.modifying.all

—————————

The Data API was included in Aurora Serverless v1 have connected it to AWS AppSync as a resolver.

With v2 this is no longer an option, and users are stuck on v1 (with its inadequate scaling), or presented with the option to add Lambda as resolvers, which not only takes time to develop, but also adds latency and maintenance to the solution.

Several requests have been made for adding the Data API to v2 through AWS support, but so far it has not been added.

Per an unspecified AWS resource of mine, the Aurora team does not plan to add the Data API anytime in the near future, if ever. It is not a planned feature for v2 (nor v3, as that is on the drawing board, apparently) which would mean that it is not happening within the next 6 months at least.

Comment: Is there any other way to use it effectively with AWS Lambda?

Comment: @eL_Finito You may try RDS Proxy, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of going serverless.

Comment: The Lambda for AppSync is fairly fast, the tests we've done is that we loose about 30% compared to the Data-API when using Node.js Lambda with knex.

Comment: AWS responded, below is the relevant bit of their response. So @Anders recommendation "please flood them with requests" looks like best option for now.  **we currently don't support Data API for Aurora Serverless v2 at the moment. We've added this request to our backlog but unfortunately we don't have a time frame for when it will be implemented. We take feature requests from our customers seriously as we engineer improvements based on customer feedback rather than what we think customers would need.

In order to expedite the feature request I have linked your case to the feature request.**

Comment: Here is a publcly-available confirmation that a Feature Request for Data API on v2 does exist: https://repost.aws/questions/QUc6tQ-_TsRWeSXAxSlqTPEg/is-data-api-for-aurora-v-2-v-3-planned   Would be great if everyone could upvote the post to give it some more visibility to AWS roadmap planners .

Comment: Indeed: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-the-data-api-for-amazon-aurora-serverless-v2-and-amazon-aurora-provisioned-clusters/

Comment: Just notice, @marracuene , that it is limited to a very few regions this far... AWS Support has said they'll add it to more regions "soon" (whatever that means) but it sucks for us as we run all EU based things in Ireland (eu-west-1) and they added the Data-API for v2 in Frankfurt only for now...

Comment: Fair point @Anders - as it happens we run most stuff in eu-west-1 too.  Although we have some other work (mainly PG and Postgis upgrades) to do before being v2 compatible.   My feeling is that if AWS have now invested in the hefty work of porting the DataAPI to v2, they will want to maximize their RoE ASAP, by making it available in other "big" regions.   So I suspect that Frankfurt is more of a "teething phase" just to ensure that no weird glitches are detected in production usage.

Answer (score 8):

RDS Data API is now available for Aurora PostGres v2:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html

——

As per [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html):

> The Data API and query editor aren't supported for Aurora Serverless v2.

Also confirmed [again](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rdsdataservice/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) with clearer wording:

> The Data Service API isn't supported on Amazon Aurora Serverless v2 DB clusters.

Comment: heard v1 will be deprecated by Feb 2023 so thinking of alternative options.

Comment: It's only MySql version being sunsetted https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.MySQL56.EOL.html

Comment: To add on to @Anders comment, MySql v1 is being sunsetted which has no correlation to Serverless v1