# Aurora Serveless - Data API no longer exists. What to do?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to create an Aurora Serverless database, using the Data API function in order to be able to access the query editor. Unfortunately, the UI was modified and I have been searching for the Data API enablement but could not find it. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciRbXZqBl7M) - 10:38 if helpful.

[image]
Could you please help me ? Maybe it's with another name but I don't know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using Aurora Serverless v2. Only [Aurora Serverless v1 supports Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html). So you have to use v1, or architect your application so that it does not require Data API.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 04/01/2024:** AWS have released the Data API for Aurora Serverless v2... hooray! Apparently only for Postgresql at the moment, but MySQL to follow.  They claim to have kept the same API signatures, but I have not tried it personally yet.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-the-data-api-for-amazon-aurora-serverless-v2-and-amazon-aurora-provisioned-clusters/

**===== original answer ===**

There is a more detailed discussion of the "Data API for AWS Aurora Serverless v2" issue here: [Does Aurora Serverless V2 have a Data API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72231268/13702327) , which should help you choose which way to go in your architecture.

If you are interested in having Data API for v2, please consider submitting a Support Request to AWS, as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72675703/13702327

Answer (score 1):

AWS has officially [launched data API for Aurora serverless v2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-the-data-api-for-amazon-aurora-serverless-v2-and-amazon-aurora-provisioned-clusters/)

Digging through it you can see that there are some limitations. First, the data API is only available for Postgresql for now and [only in certain regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.Data_API.html#Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.Data_API.apg).

Hopefully, this is only temporary and I think AWS will make the data API accessible to the different configurations (serverlessv2 and provisioned) in and all regions.