# Can Aurora Serverless v2 be used with AppSync RDS Resolvers?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-appsync, aws-aurora-serverless

We're upgrading our serverless version 1 MYSQL 5.7 database to Serverless v2 MySQL 8.0 (Aurora 3) as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.MySQL80.html#AuroraMySQL.mysql80-planning) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraMySQLReleaseNotes/AuroraMySQL.Updates.3010.html). Our current AppSync graphql API uses the RDS resolvers to access the database and call stored procedures through the Data API and it works wonderfully. In our test upgrade we've found that the Aurora 3 Serverless 2 version of the database (although available to standard connection via MySQL WorkBench) has deprecated the Data API.

So any AppSync resolvers that follow the recommended RDS AppSync pattern in the [Aurora Resolver tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds-resolvers.html) or the [RDS template mapping reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-rds.html) won't work and give the following error in CloudWatch:

```js
            "error": {
                "message": "RDSHttp:{\"message\":\"httpendpoint not enabled."}",
                "type": "400 Bad Request"
            },
```

Using `aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier <clusterid>  --enable-http-endpoint` has no effect.

The [release notice](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/04/amazon-aurora-serverless-v2/) for Aurora Serverless v2 gives RDS proxy as one of the benefits but I can't see a way to integrate that into AppSync without writing a lot of additional lambda. Can anyone tell us how to use v2 with AppSync RDS resolvers?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find out more on this? Would be interested in knowing how to use the v2 version too

Comment: Just the feedback from our AWS engineering support contact - see below in reply to Anders. We're going to hold off going to v2 until we can use the RDS resolvers.

Comment: No news still. We are trying the JS resolver and new AppSync wizard to see if any of it has been improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 2023-12-21: It would seem our wait is coming to an end!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.enabling.modifying.all

---

Please review: [Does Aurora Serverless V2 have a Data API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72231268/when-will-aurora-serverless-v2-have-a-data-api/72240641)

Basically, no, there are no set plans (but a lot of feature requests) for the Data-API.
I can only recommend you to help us flood AWS with feature requests for Data-API in Aurora Serverless v2!

Use your AWS Support channel, your AWS account rep. and AWS re:Post forums!

Comment: So in speaking with our engineering contact inside AWS, they say that it's on the road map for v2 but there's no set date. Now take that as you will -- there's no way for me to check him on that. Thanks for the encouragement @Anders!

Comment: @Alex Weinle, allow me to be a bit sceptic... If it's on the "road-map" it has a date, that's how it normally works with AWS so if it doesn't have a date it's at least more than 6 months away from hitting GA... :(

Comment: Aurora Serverless V2 doesn't support Data API yet, however we can have lambda resolver connect to our AppSync along with RDS Proxy enabled for handling connection load on RDS. Refer to this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-graphql-sql-rds-proxy/

Comment: Yes,@ibiren, I think we all are aware of that but there are some serious downsides to that approach. Performance for one (down about 30% in my tests, excluding "cold" Lambda), we would have to re-write all our VTL scripts and add Lambda functions with new code (more to maintain and build)...